# Spark cluster on Kubernetes without spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit

I have a spark application and want to deploy this on a Kubernetes cluster.
Following the below documentation I have managed to create an empty Kubernetes cluster, generated docker image using the `Dockerfile` provided under `kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile` and deployed this on the cluster using `spark-submit` in a Dev environment.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html

However, in a 'proper' environment we have a managed Kubernetes cluster (bespoke unlike EKS etc.) and will have to provide pod configuration files to get deployed.

I believe you can supply Pod template file as an argument to the `spark-submit` command.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template

How can I do this without `spark-submit`? And are there any example yaml files?

PS: we have limited access to this cluster, e.g. we can install Helm charts but not operator or controller.

Comment: This blog post might help/serve as a basis: https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-spark-on-kubernetes/ You could also compare the settings with those done by the spark-submit tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use k8s Spark CRD https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator and provide a pod configuration through it.

Comment: Thanks, but we don't have permission to install operator on this cluster. I will update the question.